# IIS could not run a windows application - .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-express

> i deploy a web application that run Adobe After Effect And Render A
>   Video, Every thing is fine when i just use iis express for my project

But On Server iis, when i start project after effect will run in task manager but didint use any source like RAM Or Cpu andit just will not work.

at first i set default user for my iis : Administrator
.net turst level is full

But I do not know what else is going to happen until this process is start and done.

this is what happen when i start my method :

[Task Manager Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP6Tz.png)

i have windows server 2016
my framework is dot net core 2

Is there a specific access for IIS?

Comment: Did you check this out? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Rendering a video probably isn't something you should do in a web app anyway. More appropriately, the request would kick off another process, like writing to a queue for instance.

Comment: You cannot automate "anything" in a web app. Learn what happens when a web app runs upon IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Like you discovered, you can only run such apps on IIS Express, which is by design.

Comment: I Can do It with Power shell ,Just help if you know answer T i just want iis run an windwos application